# Auto Layout in code and dynamic number of subviews

Tags: ios, autolayout

I want to implement a view that has a dynamic number of subviews that can be added or removed at any time. Something similar to the flow layout of UICollectionView. But it also has to size itself depending on the number of items inside.

I was planning on using Auto Layout and adding constraints programmatically but it seems that I will have to keep references to all of subview constraints, so that if one of the items gets removed I would be able to remove its constraints and update constraints of all items that follow it.

This seems really complicated, a lot more complicated than e.g. calculating frames manually in `-layoutSubviews`. Is it how Auto Layout is supposed to be used or am I misunderstanding it? Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: It depends a lot on what type of "dynamic layout" you're trying to achieve. You say "similar to Collection view / flow layout"? What do you want to do that you can't with that? Yes, it's *possible* to design a layout that cannot easily be maintained strictly with constraints... but sometimes that's due to a flaw in the layout design, rather than with auto-layout itself.